# Can we reduce YugabyteDB start time?

Tags: yugabytedb

YugabyteDB takes several seconds to start with `yugabyted`. to get a fast test environment in micro-vms, are there any undocumented flags we can pass to `yugabytedb start` that (for example) disable the 'system checks. or the web UIs, or anything else we don't need?
One other minor issue, I have to wait half a second after the `yugabytedb start` command completes before connecting to the database from node - I can just use `sleep` but it is hacky if there is another way?

Answer (score 0):

Right, `yugabyted` does a lot of pre-checks. May be better to start `yb-master` and `yb-tserver`. And for the other issue, I loop a psql until sucessful.
Example here:
https://dev.to/yugabyte/fastest-start-of-yugabytedb-for-a-small-lab-283a